# Should you use @NotNull and @JsonProperty(required) in the same object

Tags: java, json, spring, validation, jackson

So I'm looking at adding constraints to my json views.

I have class similar to this one

```
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String name;
}
```

Should I keep both `@JsonProperty(required = true)` and `@NotNull` or should I remove one and why?

---

Just to be clear since Jackson 2.6 `@JsonProperty(required = true)` does throw an [exception](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/781).

I'm using springfox-swagger and it looks like when I remove `@JsonProperty(required = true)` the field in the swagger is marked as optional which it isn't.

I'm just wondering about the best practice in this situation.

Comment: I'm using springfox-swagger and it looks like when I remove `@JsonProperty(required = true)` the field in the swagger is marked as optional.

Comment: Please let me know if my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877203/1426227) works for you

Comment: At this point I've decided to use both of them `@JsonProperty(required = true)` and `@NotNull`. I did not look into ApiModelProperty to closely mostly because `@JsonProperty` works for what I need...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) with `required` set to `true` on a field or method, *Jackson won't perform any validation*. See the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required()) for further details.

---

For validation purposes, consider [`@NotNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) from Bean Validation (a validation provider such as [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) is required to perform the validation).

With Swagger, you also can use [`@ApiModelProperty`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html) and set `required` to `true` to indicate that a field is mandatory.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I require to define the field wich can have null value?